# How to link sort function from header icon to the column to be sorted in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having problem with sorting table column in React. My table composes of three components: one defining the individual row (row.js), one rendering headers and mapping the rows that need own states (rows.js) and finally table.js that renders the whole thing. The data of the table comes from the database.

Here is a part of the row.js:

```
class ProjectTableProjectRow extends Component {

  render() {
    const { project } = this.props;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td className="projects">
          <Body2>
            <Link to={`/projects/${project.id}`}>{project.description}</Link>
          </Body2>
        </td>

export default withRouter(ProjectTableProjectRow);
```

And here an excerpt from my rows.js:

```
class ProjectTableProjectRows extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.projects.getAll(); // This gets all the projects from the store
  }

  onSortProjects = () => {
    let sortedToBe = this.props.projects.list.map(project => project.description);
    const sorted = sortedToBe.sort();

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <Caption>Project</Caption>
              <IconButton onClick={() => this.onSortProjects()}>
                <RowsIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {this.props.projects.list.map(project => (
          <tbody key={project.id}>
            <ProjectTableProjectRow project={project} />
          </tbody>
        ))}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectTableProjectRows;
```

Finally, there is a projectTable.js (that I am not sure if  I need anyway...)

```
class ProjectTable extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ProjectTableProjectRows projects={this.props.projects} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ProjectTable;
```

So, I'd like to sort the project.description column (there are project names as strings) in alphabetical order. Naturally the icon and sort function onClick in it is not connected to the table column, so the sort function does nothing to the table. How can I achieve this? I do not know yet how to think "in React".

Comment: You are mapping over the projects passed in by props, so when you sort the projects nothing is going to update. You need to sort the projects and then save that sorted list to state and map over that value instead. So maybe in your componentDidMount call setState with the results of `this.props.projects.getAll();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously not tested, I'm just making a couple of updates to the code you had but this will allow you to use the sorted values.

```js
class ProjectTableProjectRows extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      projects: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const projects = this.props.projects.getAll();
    this.setState({ projects })
  }

  onSortProjects = () => {
    let sortedToBe = this.state.projects.list.map(project => project.description);
    const sorted = sortedToBe.sort();
    this.setState({ projects: sorted });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <Caption>Project</Caption>
              <IconButton onClick={() => this.onSortProjects()}>
                <RowsIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {this.state.projects && this.state.projects.list.map(project => (
          <tbody key={project.id}>
            <ProjectTableProjectRow project={project} />
          </tbody>
        ))}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectTableProjectRows;
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not work as such, but with some changes (to sort function and to componentDidMount) got the column sorted as I understood the logic from your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped in some way 